# Expand array type column to data from referencing table (Metadata query)

Tags: postgresql, metadata, postgresql-9.1

I'm constructing queries using Postgres' metadata tables ([system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalogs.html)) to fetch some information I need. The [`pg_constraint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) catalog has a column called `conkey` which is of type `int2[]` and it references [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)`.attnum`.

My question is not about system catalogs itself, but rather about how I can expand this `int2[]` array into an array of actual column names. For example:

```
a) pg_constraint:
conname | conrelid | conkey
const1  | 123      | {2, 3}

b) pg_class:
oid | relname
123 | table1

c) pg_attribute:
attrelid | attname | attnum
123      | colA    | 1
123      | colB    | 2
123      | colC    | 3
```

How do I get the `const_columns` in the expected result as below?

```
pseudo-query:
select b.relname as table, a.conname as constraint,
    /******> a.conkey expanded to c.attname <******/ as const_columns
    from pg_constraint a, pg_class b, pg_attribute c
    where a.conrelid = b.oid
    and c.attrelid = b.oid
    and a.conkey = c.attnum;

expected result:
table  | constraint | const_columns
table1 | const1     | {colB, colC}
```

Comment: I figured out how to do this _indirectly_ using `unnest`, `array_agg` and nested queries, but I would like to know if there's a way to do it _directly_ (without such nesting): take the array and replace each element in the array at the exact position to another column in a referencing table from the row that matches the element (and specified keys).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
    b.relname as table,
    a.conname as constraint,
    array_agg(c.attname) as const_columns
from pg_constraint a, pg_class b, pg_attribute c
where
    a.conrelid = b.oid
    and c.attrelid = b.oid
    and c.attnum in (select unnest(a.conkey))
group by b.relname, a.conname
```

Or using an array operator:

```
    and array[c.attnum] <@ a.conkey
```

Comment: Nice try. But `c.attnum in a.conkey` or even `c.attnum in unnest(a.conkey)` doesn't work.

Comment: **Both constructs work!** What's the difference between the two? Is it the `in (select unnest(` construct doesn't care about the conkey order, but the `array[...] <@ conkey` will match element-for-element in order? Also, what is `<@`? :)

Comment: I wish I could unnest an array aggregate of upvotes for you